# External Merge Sort

Tags: database, sorting, merge

I am trying to implement External merge sort for my DBMS project. I have a 3 file each with 20 pages and my buffer size is 20 pages . 
Each of these i have sorted now . So all three files of 20 pages are sorted. Now  while merging i need to bring 6 pages  of each files (6x3=18 pages ) and 1 page to write the sorted output . And this has to be done 4 times to get whole file complete sorted .
But i am finding difficult to merge all these files ? any steps how to perform merge of 3 files making sure that every pages is brought in buffer size .Any recursive function ?
All the files content are stored in array a[fileno][pageno] format 
eg a[1][20] =5 mean i have a data of 5 in the page no 20 of File 1 .
Assuming the page of a file hold an integer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do a 3 way merge, that's 3 inputs and 1 output, and it only has to be done once. Divide buffer into 4 parts, 5 pages each. Start by reading the first 5 pages of the 3 files, each into it's on 5 page buffer. Start a 3 way merge by comparing the first records in each of the 3 buffers and move the smallest to the output buffer. When the output buffer is filled (5 pages), write it out and continue. When an input buffer is emptied, read in the next 5 pages for that file.

When the end of one of the three input files is reached, the code switches to a 2 way merge. To simplify the code, copy the file related parameters into the parameters for file 0 and file 1. If file 2 goes empty first, nothing needs to be done. If file 1 goes empty first, copy file 2 parameters to file 1. If file 0 goes empty first, copy file 1 parameters to file 0, then file 2 parameters to file1. Then do the 2 way merge using file 0 and file 1.

When the end of of the two input files is reaches, the code switches to just copy the remaining file. Again, if file 0 goes empty first, then copy file 1 parameters to file 0, so that the copy code always works with file 0.